How to calculate the inner product $ \langle T|x \rangle = \langle\frac{p^2}{2\mu} |x\rangle$?
If I have a wave function $ \psi (x) = \langle x|\psi \rangle$, now I want to use kinetic energy representation $$ T = \frac{p^2}{2\mu} ,$$ where $ \mu $ is the mass of particle. I try to
\begin{align*}
\langle T|\psi \rangle = \int {\rm d} x \langle T|x \rangle \langle x|\psi \rangle
\end{align*}
But how to calculate $ \langle T|x \rangle $? May be I can write
\begin{align*}
\langle T|x \rangle = \int {\rm d} p' \langle T|p' \rangle \langle p'|x \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \int {\rm d} p' \delta_{\frac{p^2}{2\mu},p'} e^{-\frac{ip'x}{\hbar}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} e^{-\frac{ip^2x}{2\mu}}
\end{align*}
I don't know something wrong above. And I try to find the eigen equation
\begin{align*}
\hat{T} |T\rangle = T|T\rangle
\end{align*}
where $ T $ is the eigen value. But as we know, $ [T,p] = 0 $, so I choose $ |p> $ as the eigen state of $ T $. Then
\begin{align*}
\hat{T} |p \rangle = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2\mu}|p \rangle = \frac{p^2}{2\mu}|p \rangle
\end{align*}
In this, $ \frac{p^2}{2\mu} \neq p $.
The solution use a strange equation
\begin{align*}
F(T){\rm d}T=2|\varphi(p)|^2{\rm d}p
\end{align*}
it seem plausibly. Back to my question, how to get $ \langle T|x \rangle = \langle \frac{p^2}{2\mu} |x \rangle $?

What do you mean by $|T\rangle$? Do you mean an eigenstate of the translation operator, or something else?

@11zaq of the Kinetic energy operator

@liZ Hint: you should use the fact that $[T,p]=0$ implies that there is a base of common eigenstates (the difference is that T "doesn't differentiate" between positive and negative momentum).

in position space, the momentum operator is given by $\hat{p} = i\hbar\nabla$. Given this, you should be able to find the eigenstates of $T$, and then calculate the inner product of those with your wavefunction.

"The solution" suggests a homework problem poorly transmitted. There is a double degeneracy involved, as both $|p\rangle$ and $|-p\rangle$ have the same eigenvalue T.

Are you perhaps looking for $\langle \psi| \hat T| \psi\rangle$, instead ? The coordinate basis seems out of place here...

Your notation makes no sense. What are you really trying to calculate? The probability that the particle has some kinetic energy $T_0$ or what?

Are you asking how you define and normalize $\langle   p^2    |p\rangle$ ?

Indeed, in your odd notation, for $\hat T =\hat p^2/2\mu$, a good (overgenerous!) basis for the eigenstates of  $\hat T$ would be $|p\rangle$. Both signs of p will yield the same doubly degenerate T eigenvalue (positive semidefinite$^\natural$),
$\hat T|p\rangle =  T|p\rangle, \quad \hat T|-p\rangle =  T|-p\rangle$.
Then,
$$
\langle T|\hat T|x\rangle = \langle p| {\hat p^2 \over 2\mu} |x\rangle =  { p^2 \over 2\mu } ~ \langle p |x\rangle =  { p^2 \over 2\mu\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} ~  e^{-ixp/\hbar} .
$$
From this, you may compute $\langle x|\hat T |x\rangle$, as usual.

$^\natural$  The one-to-two states map evokes your factor of 2; in this language,
$$ \hat T= \int_0^\infty\! \!\!dT~~|T\rangle T\langle T|
=\int_0^\infty\! \!\! dp~~\left (|p\rangle\frac{p^2}{2\mu}\langle p|+|\!-p\rangle \frac{p^2}{2\mu}\langle - p|\right )\\ 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\! \!\! dp~~|p\rangle \frac{p^2}{2\mu}\langle p|    
~.$$

Use $\langle x|\hat p |\psi\rangle = -i\hbar\partial_x  \langle x|\psi\rangle$

@mikestone I suspect that was meant to be a comment on the question
